# How to get alertdialog() when the application is minimized?

Tags: android, sms, android-alertdialog

I am new at Android developement.

Currently, I am developing receiving sms kind of application, which receives the sms and displays the alertdialog() for text to speech functionality option. I do call the method for alertdialog() in another class from Broadcastreceiver class. When the application is running, the alertdialog() appears, but after pressing the Home button, it doesn't.

So, what should I do?

Please help me.

Comment: You can't display an AlertDialog if your activity isn't visible. See below for better suggestions!

Answer (score 7):

Consider using a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html). If you need user interaction, consider a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html).

Don't try to pop up a big dialog when your app is not in the foreground, that would be utterly intrusive.

Comment: But I want to implement text to speech using button in alertdialog.

Comment: Implement that as a statusbar notification.

Comment: Let's say the user is talking on the phone right now, and all of a sudden you want to butt in and do some text-to-speech? Bad style. Don't do that.

Comment: Its ok.But how can it appear when the app is minimized?

Comment: Both toasts and notifications will always appear, that's what they're designed to be - a non-intrusive way to get the user's attention when your app is not in the foreground.